# div get shrinked when using postion: fixed

Tags: html, css

I'm having a `<div>` and I want to make it's `position: fixed`. I've added *CSS* rule `position:fixed` but after adding that the `<div>` gets shrink.

[image]

[image]

Please guide me into this.

my html code is this

```
<div layout="row" style="background-color:#1CA5EA; position:fixed">

    <div offset="25" flex="30" class="input-container">
       <md-input-container flex >
          <label style="color:white">Search</label>
          <input ng-model="search" style="border-bottom:2px solid white;color:white;">
       </md-input-container>
    </div>

    <div flex="10" class="input-container">
       <button class="primary-button md-button md-default-theme">
         <span class="ng-scope" ui-sref="company.addRecruitmentProject">
           + JOB AD
         </span>
       </button>
    </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Add related html and css code here.

Comment: @SrinivasPai i have added the code here.

Comment: @Sidsec9 I'm using inline css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `width:100%;` for that div.

```
<div layout="row" style="background-color:#1CA5EA; position:fixed; width:100%;">

    <div offset="25" flex="30" class="input-container">
       <md-input-container flex >
          <label style="color:white">Search</label>
          <input ng-model="search" style="border-bottom:2px solid white;color:white;">
       </md-input-container>
    </div>

    <div flex="10" class="input-container">
       <button class="primary-button md-button md-default-theme">
         <span class="ng-scope" ui-sref="company.addRecruitmentProject">
           + JOB AD
         </span>
       </button>
    </div>

 </div>
```

[**Demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/envnagzu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

May be other div or element of Html make effect on the Div. thats why your div gets shrinked. and secondly please add your css code here then after i can resolve your problem hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you should define the width of your `<div>` whose position is fixed.
Let's say for example:

```
.div {
   width: 80%; // or whatever you want to be the size
}
```